# Affiliate Plus Magento customer account full integration

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have Magento module Magestore Affiliate Plus. This module use customer account from magento but user must click "add to affiliate".

I'd like to each register customer to affiliate plus database table.

My question: I need to modify or create new module, copy customer module from core and owerwrite?

I need only add one record in database for each new register user. I work on magento 1.7